# Better way to add label data to convolutional neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am working on an image classification CNN to practice understanding machine learning, and I want to be as vanilla as possible to really get a concrete understanding of what is happening while also remaining somewhat efficient.

I have a directory structure that goes like this:

```
training folder 
     3 folders named 0, 1, 2
          0 contains only pictures of cats
          1 contains only pictures of dogs
          2 contains only pictures of ducks
testing folder 
     3 folders named 0, 1, 2
          0 contains only pictures of cats
          1 contains only pictures of dogs
          2 contains only pictures of ducks
```

I created this snippet of code to go through folder 0, convert all images(of cats) to image array, then go to folder 1 and do the same for all images(of dogs), and finally go to folder 2 and repeat for ducks. I then converted that returned list into a numpy array defined as x_train to feed into the model.

```
def get_img_array(dir):
    for num in range(0,3):
        image_list = [img for img in os.listdir(dir + str(num)) if img.endswith('.jpg')]
        for img_name in range(0,len(image_list)):
            loaded_image = image.load_img(dir + str(num) + '\\' + str(image_list[img_name]), grayscale = False)
            process_img = image.img_to_array(loaded_image)
            processed_list.append(process_img/255)
    return processed_list
```

but I'm not sure of how to move forward giving them the label y_train and y_test

I'm aware I could create a csv file with the name of each image and a corresponding label such as "0", "1", and "2" in the next column depending on the picture and import them that way, but I'm curious to see if there is a better and more efficient way to add labels with the structure I currently have?

I've tried to research and look over GitHub repos, guides, and SO questions([Convolutional Neural Networks labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113867/convolutional-neural-networks-labels) unfortunately doesn't have a useful answer) but I've only come across data sets that were hardly explained, or it was imported from a database pre-labeled in some way unknown to me, so an in-depth explanation would be great!

Comment: You should have a look at this example https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images, which focuses on how to prepare your image data before training.

Comment: Sweet, this will be a good read for future applications. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create label array same time when you create pixel array.Lets assume your categories are `cat=0,dog=1,ducks=2`.initialize a empty numpy array and create label array for each folder.and concatenate the each array for get the final labels.

```
def get_img_array(dir):
    labels_arr= np.empty(shape=[0,1])
    for num in range(0,3):
        image_list = [img for img in os.listdir(dir + str(num)) if img.endswith('.jpg')]
        for img_name in range(0,len(image_list)):
            loaded_image = image.load_img(dir + str(num) + '\\' + str(image_list[img_name]), grayscale = False)
            process_img = image.img_to_array(loaded_image)
            processed_list.append(process_img/255)
        labels = np.full((len(image_list),1),num)
        labels_arr= np.concatenate((labels_arr, labels))
    return processed_list,labels_arr
```

Check this answer as well for more intuitive. 
[How to prepare training data for image classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294900/how-to-prepare-training-data-for-image-classification/59296781#59296781)

Comment: Ahh, thank you! This was super helpful. I've studied the three new lines you've added and completely understand what is happening. I will study the other link soon.